# Obj-C, NSScanner: nil string argument, suddenly getting this warning, how do I fix it?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring

I'm suddenly getting this warning `NSScanner: nil string argument` in the debug window.

I say suddenly, but I've no idea from which code has caused it.

How do I resolve this problem ?

Comment: What does your application do, and where do you use an nsscanner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check if the string is nil before creating the NSScanner with it, as you are probably creating it with

```
+ (id)scannerWithString:(NSString *)aString
```

or

```
- (id)initWithString:(NSString *)aString
```

There is no way of changing the NSScanner string, once it has been created, the compiler is just telling you that it is pointless to create a NSScanner with a nil string.

Answer (score 0):

I had solved this problem by `removeObserver:forKeyPath:` in `dealloc` where I had used KVO.